# Storing photos locally persistently

Tags: ios, swift

I want to store a couple of images locally in my app on the user's device.
What I was using until now (it's still in development):

```
    static func filePath(forKey key: String) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        guard let documentURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                 in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
        
        return documentURL.appendingPathComponent(key + ".png")
    }

    static func savePhoto(imageKey: String) {
        if let filePath = Helpers.filePath(forKey: imageKey) {
            do {
                try Constants.PHOTO_DATA.write(to: filePath, options: .atomic)
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        } else {
            print(" >>> Error during saving photo. Filepath couldn't be created.")
        }
    }

    static func getPhoto(imageKey: String) -> (image: UIImage, placeholder: Bool) {
        if let filePath = Helpers.filePath(forKey: imageKey),
           let fileData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath.path),
           let image = UIImage(data: fileData) {
               // Retrieve image from device
               return (image, false)
        }
        return (UIImage(named: "placeholder")!, true)
    }
```

Now, during testing I realized that it is not working (but I'm almost 100% sure it was working until now, strange..). It is changing the App's container directory upon every launch.

E.g.

```
Path:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F3E812E-B128-481C-9724-5E39049D6C81/Documents/D5F14199-CFBF-402A-9894-3487976C4C74.png
Restarting the app, then the path it gives (and where it does not find the image):
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0A9FCE45-1ED4-46EB-A91B-3ECD56E6A31B/Documents/D5F14199-CFBF-402A-9894-3487976C4C74.png
```

I read a bit and as far as I see it is 'expected' that it is not working, as the app's directory  can change any time the user restarts the app. I should use bookmarkData of the URL class.

My problem is that I couldn't get it working with bookmarkData as I don't really see how should I use it, and couldn't understand its behavior based on some example codes/articles I found. Until now I was simply using URLs to store/retrieve the photo but now I should go with this bookmarkData which is a Data type, which confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want your code means, since both Helper and Constants.PHOTO_DATA are unknown. The code that will definitely will save a UIImage in the documents directory is here:

```
class ImageSaver {

    private let imageStore = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first

    //Make this static variable to allow access from all objects without instantiating this class
    static var shared : AuxiliaryObjects {
        return AuxiliaryObjects()
    }

    /**
     Declaration: save(image : UIImage, with fileName: String, and imageName: String?)
     
     Description: This method saves the received image to the persistent store in the documents directory of the user.
     
     - Parameter image: The UIImage object that must be stored in the documents directory.
     - Parameter fileName: A string with the name under which the image must be stored.
     - Parameter imageName: The name of the image if needed.
     */
    func save(image: UIImage, with fileName: String, and imageName: String?) {

        let fileStore = imageStore?.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        
        do {
            try imageData?.write(to: fileStore!)
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't write the image to disk.")
        }
    }

    /**
     Declaration: getImage(with fileName: String, with rectangle: CGRect) -> UIImage?
     
     Description: This method retrieves the image with the specified file name and a given size. 
     
     - Parameter fileName: a string with the file name to retrieve.
     - Parameter rectangle: the size of the image to return.
     
     - Returns: UIImage?, the image retrieved from the documents directory.
    */
    func getImage(with fileName: String, with rectangle: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        
        var returnImage : UIImage?
        var imageRectangle = rectangle
        
        do {
            imageStoreArray = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: imageStore!, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys, options: .skipsHiddenFiles) as [NSURL]
        } catch {
            return returnImage
        }

        for url in imageStoreArray {
            
            let urlString = url.lastPathComponent
            
            if urlString == fileName {
                
                let retrievedImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
                
                //When there is no size set, the original size image is returned
                if (rectangle.size.height > 0) || (rectangle.size.width > 0) {
                    let imageWidth = retrievedImage?.size.width
                    let imageHeight = retrievedImage?.size.height
                    
                    if imageWidth! > imageHeight!
                    {
                        //The picture is wider than it is high
                        imageRectangle.size.height *= (imageHeight! / imageWidth!)
                    } else {
                        imageRectangle.size.width *= (imageWidth! / imageHeight!)
                    }
                    
                    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRectangle.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
                    retrievedImage?.draw(in: imageRectangle)
                    returnImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                } else {
                    returnImage = retrievedImage
                }
            }
        }
        
        return returnImage
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: Why would you need to get the whole contents of a directory to load a single image? btw `FileManager()` will create a new file manager every time you call that method. What you should be using if `FileManager.default` but in this case you should simply construct the image url and try to load its contents. Looks like you probably had a hard time with the fact that iOS is sandboxed and the file location changes every time the app is launched. saving the file name and reconstructing the url is all you need.

Comment: You're absolutely right about the FileManager(). I changed that. I was sloppy here, using some old code, that I didn't clean up before posting. The last function is retrieving a specific image in a directory where several files are stored. I thought at that time, when I wrote the code, that that would be the best way to do it. I think you're right when there are more optimal ways if the code cn be more specific to a single purpose.

Comment: Thank you MacUserT, but as far as I see it is almost the same way as I did, and I experience that the path changese upon every restart of the app so I can't locate my image anymore. I can't test the code today, but if I'm wrong can you help me what part solves my problem? I dont' really see the difference between your and mine code.
@LeoDabus, you mentioned that the location changes every time. My problem is exactly this, how can I reconstruct the URL and get the file that is now saved in a different directory - as it was saved previously when the app had different path?